# Parsing multiple JSON arrays into html

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, rest, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to parse this api:http://www.fulek.com/VUA/SUPIT/GetCategoriesAndFoods
into html, and I can parse first array in the html, but cannot get values inside second array.
My code looks like this, and i'm I on a right track with second for loop?

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", 'http://www.fulek.com/VUA/SUPIT/GetCategoriesAndFoods', 
true);
xhr.onload = function() {
if  (this.status == 200) {
    var menu = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    var output = '';
    var outputArr = '';
    for(var i in menu) {
        output += 
        '<div id="menu">' + 
        '<p>' + menu[i].Id + '</p>' +
        '<p>' + menu[i].Naziv + '</p>'
        for(var j in menu) {
            outputArr +=
        '<div class="cuisine">' + 
        '<p>' + menu[j].JeloId + '</p>' +
        '<p>' + menu[j].Naziv + '</p>' +
        '<p>' + menu[j].Opis + '</p>' +  
        '<p>' + menu[j].Cijena + '</p>' +  
        '</div>' +
        '</div>'
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = output;
    document.getElementsByClassName('cuisine').innerHTML = outputArr;

 }
};

xhr.send();
```

I'm trying to display it as a div inside a div.
this is my html page:

```
<body>

    <div id="menu">
        <div class="cuisine">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want to parse from text "Ponuda" array contents in the div called cuisine
[image]

Comment: Have you parsed the json? It looks like it is not well formatted. When I test it on https://jsonformatter.org/ it gives an error: Parse error on line 1:
... brokula, carrots, "JeloId": 11, "Name":
-----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'undefined'

Comment: it's a school assignment and it's formatted. But i'm doing something wrong in the second for loop obv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using DOM elements instead of strings. This are really confusing.

The ideea is: have container div, a list of menu divs, a list of offer divs.
Iterate first array and then get the objects (including offer array). Append menu div in container.
Then iterate through second array, get objects and append cuisine div in menu div.

The snippet does not work due to "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID", but if you copy it in your project, it will.
Here I provided complete code with result.

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", 'http://www.fulek.com/VUA/SUPIT/GetCategoriesAndFoods',
    true);
xhr.onload = function () {
    if (this.status == 200) {
        processResponse(this.responseText)
    }
};

xhr.send();

function processResponse(responseText) {
    var menu = JSON.parse(responseText);
    console.log(menu)

    let menuDivContainer = document.getElementById("container")

    for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
        let menuItem = menu[i]
        // Get desired objects
        let id = menuItem.Id
        let name = menuItem.Naziv
        let offerArray = menuItem.Ponuda

        // Create menu item div with class
        let menuDivItem = document.createElement("div")
        menuDivItem.innerHTML = `${id}: ${name}`
        menuDivItem.classList.add("menu")

        // Append menuDivItem in menuDivContainer
        menuDivContainer.appendChild(menuDivItem)

        // Loop in offerArray
        for (var j = 0; j < offerArray.length; j++) {

            // Get objects from offer
            let offer = offerArray[j]
            let offerId = offer.JeloId
            let offerName = offer.Naziv
            let price = offer.Cijena
            let description = offer.Opis

            // Create div element
            let offerDiv = document.createElement("div")
            offerDiv.innerHTML = `${offerId}: ${offerName} ${price} ${description}`
            offerDiv.classList.add("cuisine")

            // Append offerDiv in menuDivItem
            menuDivItem.appendChild(offerDiv)
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

> 1: PREPORUKA ŠEFA KUHINJE
>   3: Patka szechuan 56 hrskava patka, povrće, ljuto
>   10: Junetina i brokula 47 Junetina, brokula, mrkva, luk, ljuto
>   11: Piletina s indijskim oraščićima 44 Piletina, crvena paprika, luk, ljuto
>   12: Piletina s curry-em 42 Piletina, luk, curry, blago
>   13: Patka u slatko kiselom umaku 51 Patka, paprika, riža, luk, ljuto
>   14: Patka szechuan 56 hrskava patka, povrće, ljuto
>   15: Patka Yaoux 51 Hrskava patka, umak od češnjaka
>   2: TOPLA PREDJELA
>   4: Proljetna rolada s mesom 14 mljevena junetina, povrće ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're iterating through the response the right way. Please try this instead

```
if  (this.status == 200) {
    var menu = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    var output = '';
    var outputArr = '';
    for(var i=0; i < menu.length; i++) {
        output += 
        '<div id="menu">' + 
        '<p>' + menu[i].Id + '</p>' +
        '<p>' + menu[i].Naziv + '</p>';
        var innerArray = menu[i].Ponuda;

        for(var j = 0; j < innerArray.length; j++) {
            outputArr +=
        '<div class="cuisine">' + 
        '<p>' + innerArray[j].JeloId + '</p>' +
        '<p>' + innerArray[j].Naziv + '</p>' +
        '<p>' + innerArray[j].Opis + '</p>' +  
        '<p>' + innerArray[j].Cijena + '</p>' +  
        '</div>' +
        '</div>'
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = output;
    document.getElementsByClassName('cuisine').innerHTML = outputArr;

 }
```

Comment: i tried your code and outer array is working fine, but inner returns nothing. do you have any other idea how could i parse it all?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this code. mybe use a repl. - try to understand - and adapt it to your task:

```js
var jsonMenu = JSON.parse('[{"Id":1,"Naziv":"PREPORUKA ŠEFA KUHINJE","Ponuda":[{"JeloId":3,"Naziv":"Patka szechuan","Opis":"hrskava patka, povrće, ljuto","Cijena":56},{"JeloId":10,"Naziv":"Junetina i brokula","Opis":"Junetina, brokula, mrkva, luk, ljuto","Cijena":47},{"JeloId":11,"Naziv":"Piletina s indijskim oraščićima","Opis":"Piletina, crvena paprika, luk, ljuto","Cijena":44},{"JeloId":12,"Naziv":"Piletina s curry-em","Opis":"Piletina, luk, curry, blago","Cijena":42},{"JeloId":13,"Naziv":"Patka u slatko kiselom umaku","Opis":"Patka, paprika, riža, luk, ljuto","Cijena":51},{"JeloId":14,"Naziv":"Patka szechuan","Opis":"hrskava patka, povrće, ljuto","Cijena":56},{"JeloId":15,"Naziv":"Patka Yaoux","Opis":"Hrskava patka, umak od češnjaka","Cijena":51}]},{"Id":2,"Naziv":"TOPLA PREDJELA","Ponuda":[{"JeloId":4,"Naziv":"Proljetna rolada s mesom","Opis":"mljevena junetina, povrće","Cijena":14},{"JeloId":16,"Naziv":"Proljetna rolada s povrćem (2 kom)","Opis":"Prilog","Cijena":13},{"JeloId":17,"Naziv":"Proljetna rolada s mesom (2 kom)","Opis":"Mljevena junetina, povrće","Cijena":14},{"JeloId":18,"Naziv":"Čips od jastoga","Opis":"Čips, slatko kiseli umak","Cijena":16}]},{"Id":3,"Naziv":"KINESKE JUHE","Ponuda":[{"JeloId":19,"Naziv":"Kineska kiselo ljuta juha","Opis":"Ljuto","Cijena":15},{"JeloId":20,"Naziv":"Kineska juha od bambusa i gljiva","Opis":"Blago","Cijena":17}]},{"Id":4,"Naziv":"JELA SA REZANCIMA","Ponuda":[{"JeloId":21,"Naziv":"Rezanci s povrćem","Opis":"Povrće, jaja","Cijena":34},{"JeloId":22,"Naziv":"Rezanci s piletinom i povrćem","Opis":"Piletina, povrće","Cijena":35},{"JeloId":23,"Naziv":"Rezanci 3 vrste mesa i povrćem","Opis":"piletina, svinjetina, junetina, povrće","Cijena":38},{"JeloId":24,"Naziv":"Rezanci Szechuan","Opis":"piletina, povrće, ljuto","Cijena":46},{"JeloId":25,"Naziv":"Rezanci Gonbao","Opis":"piletina, povrće, kikiriki, ljuto","Cijena":47},{"JeloId":26,"Naziv":"Rezanci piletina, bambus i gljive","Opis":"piletina, bambus,kineske shitake gljive","Cijena":50},{"JeloId":27,"Naziv":"Rezanci 8 blaga","Opis":"piletina, svinjetina, junetina, kozice, povrće, ljuto","Cijena":51},{"JeloId":28,"Naziv":"Rezanci mongolsko meso","Opis":"junetina, poriluk, đumbir","Cijena":52},{"JeloId":29,"Naziv":"Rezanci s piletinom u slatko kiselom umaku","Opis":"piletina u kineskom tijestu, prelivena s kiselim umakom","Cijena":46},{"JeloId":48,"Naziv":"Rezanci s patkom Yaoux","Opis":"hrskava patka, umak od češnjaka","Cijena":56},{"JeloId":49,"Naziv":"Rezanci lignje Yaoux (pržene)","Opis":"pržene lignje, umak od češnjaka","Cijena":46},{"JeloId":50,"Naziv":"Rezanci s patkom u slatko kiselom umaku","Opis":"Blago","Cijena":56},{"JeloId":51,"Naziv":"Rezanci s piletinom i indijskim orašćićima","Opis":"Velika porcija","Cijena":49}]},{"Id":5,"Naziv":"JELA S PILETINOM","Ponuda":[{"JeloId":30,"Naziv":"Slatko-kisela piletina + prilog","Opis":"piletina u kineskom tijestu, prelivena s kiselim umakom","Cijena":40},{"JeloId":31,"Naziv":"Piletina Szechuan + riža","Opis":"piletina, povrće (ljuto)","Cijena":41},{"JeloId":32,"Naziv":"Piletina Gonbao + riža","Opis":"piletina, povrće, kikiriki (ljuto)","Cijena":42},{"JeloId":33,"Naziv":"Piletina s bambusom i gljivama + riža","Opis":"piletina, bambus, kineske shiitake gljive","Cijena":45},{"JeloId":52,"Naziv":"Piletina s bambusom i gljivama + riža","Opis":"piletina, bambus, kineske shiitake gljive","Cijena":45},{"JeloId":53,"Naziv":"8 blaga (3 vrste mesa) + riža","Opis":"piletina, svinjetina, junetina, kozice, povrće (ljuto)","Cijena":46}]},{"Id":6,"Naziv":"JELA SA POVRĆEM","Ponuda":[{"JeloId":34,"Naziv":"Veggie wok + riža","Opis":"povrće u wok-u","Cijena":32}]},{"Id":7,"Naziv":"JELA SA SVINJETINOM","Ponuda":[{"JeloId":35,"Naziv":"Svinjetina Szechuan + riža","Opis":"svinjetina, povrće, ljuto","Cijena":43},{"JeloId":36,"Naziv":"Gonbao svinjetina + riža","Opis":"svinjetina, povrće, kikiriki, ljuto","Cijena":44},{"JeloId":37,"Naziv":"Svinjetina s bambusom i gljivama + riža","Opis":"svinjetina, bambus, kineske shitake gljive","Cijena":47}]},{"Id":8,"Naziv":"JELA S JUNETINOM","Ponuda":[{"JeloId":38,"Naziv":"Mongolsko meso + riža","Opis":"junetina, poriluk, đumbir","Cijena":47},{"JeloId":39,"Naziv":"Junetina Szechuan + riža","Opis":"junetina, poriluk, đumbir, ljuto","Cijena":45},{"JeloId":40,"Naziv":"Gonbao junetina + riža","Opis":"junetina, poriluk, đumbir, kikiriki, ljuto","Cijena":46}]},{"Id":9,"Naziv":"SPECIJALITETI","Ponuda":[{"JeloId":41,"Naziv":"Lignje yaoux","Opis":"pržene, umak od češnjaka","Cijena":40},{"JeloId":42,"Naziv":"Kozice \u0026 Brokula","Opis":"kozice, brokula, riža","Cijena":59}]},{"Id":10,"Naziv":"PIĆA","Ponuda":[{"JeloId":43,"Naziv":"Ledeni čaj breskva","Opis":"0.5l","Cijena":13},{"JeloId":44,"Naziv":"Pago jabuka","Opis":"0.2l","Cijena":13},{"JeloId":45,"Naziv":"Coca-cola 0,5l","Opis":"Plastična boca","Cijena":13},{"JeloId":46,"Naziv":"Sprite 0,5L","Opis":"Pla","Cijena":0},{"JeloId":47,"Naziv":"Fanta 0,5L","Opis":"Plastična boca","Cijena":13}]}]');

for (let i = 0; i < jsonMenu.length; i++) {
  console.log('-----------------------------------')
  console.log(jsonMenu[i].Id);
  console.log(jsonMenu[i].Naziv);
  for (let j = 0; j < jsonMenu[i].Ponuda.length; j++) {
    console.log('-----------------------------------')
    console.log('\t JeloId:',jsonMenu[i].Ponuda[j].JeloId);
    console.log('\t Naziv:',jsonMenu[i].Ponuda[j].Naziv);
    console.log('\t Opis:',jsonMenu[i].Ponuda[j].Opis);
    console.log('\t Cijena:',jsonMenu[i].Ponuda[j].Cijena);
  }
}
```

Comment: hey, i implemented your code, but still i cannot render html on the second div(second for loop). it returns no errors

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
var menu = xhr;
var output = '';
var outputArr = '';
for(var i in menu) {
    outputArr = '';
    output += 
    '<div id="menu">' + 
    '<p>' + menu[i].Id + '</p>' +
    '<p>' + menu[i].Naziv + '</p>'

 for(var j in menu[i]["Ponuda"]){
            outputArr +=
      '<div class="cuisine">' + 
      '<p>' + menu[i]["Ponuda"][j]["JeloId"] + '</p>' + 
       '<p>' + menu[i]["Ponuda"][j]["Naziv"] + '</p>' + 
        '<p>' + menu[i]["Ponuda"][j]["Opis"] + '</p>' + 
         '<p>' + menu[i]["Ponuda"][j]["Cijena"] + '</p>' +
           '</div>' + '</div>';

  }
  output += outputArr;

}

document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML += output;
```

to save everything inside `<div id="menu">`